# Performance using T-SQL PIVOT vs SSIS PIVOT Transformation Component

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am in process of building Dimension from EDW (source), wherein I need to pivot columns of source to load Dimension.

Currently most of the pivoting stuff am doing is by using T-SQL PIVOT which further get used in my SSIS package to merge with Dim table

This pivoting can also be achieved by SSIS PIVOT Transformation component.

In regards to Performance which approach would be the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory, SQL Server pivot perf should be faster, or at least the same, but to be sure, requires doing some perf comparison tests.

But even if SSIS currently has the advantage, feel free to use SQL Server, as staying out of SSIS is a *good thing*.